# Using jQuery.not() chained with jQuery.html()

Tags: jquery, chaining

Is it possible to use `jQuery.not()` chained with `jQuery.html()`?

```
winner.not('a').html()
```

Where `winner` is a jQuery object/wrapped set, I am trying to return HTML with anchors removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.html()` is going to return the innerHTML - which will include any A tags inside, you may be able to do something like this though:

```
// clone the matched div:
var copy = winner.clone();
// remove all A tags from the DOM
copy.find("a").remove();
// get the html.
var noanchors = copy.html();
```

Also - If you wanted to get the text within the A still - but not the A itself - you could use:

```
// for each A tag
copy.find("a").each(function() {
  //insert the text within ourselves to the document directly before us.
  $(this).before($(this).text());
  // then delete ourselves
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Although that might actually get a little messy if the `<a>` has any other tags within it - it should illustrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks, clone() is perfect in this situation. Why didn't I think of that? And per your second code block, it's useful towards the next bit of logic I need to write.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but that won't give you the result you expect. `not('a')` will filter `a` tags from your `winner` collection but `html()` will return you the value of the first item in the collection.

so if your `winner` has `[div#i1 div#i2 a div#i3 a]`, `not('a')` will reduce this set to `[div#i1 div#i2 div#i3]` and `html()` will return HTML contents of `div#i1`.

If you want to remove anchors from HTML I think you should first get is using `.html()` method and then do a replace on the value returned with some regular expression that will strip the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
var noanchors = '';
winner.not('a').each(function() { noanchors = noanchors + $(this).html(); )
```

to get the concatenation of the non-a elements' html. However, this may miss any top-level text in between the various tag-enclosed items.